# Order of the zero of the following complex functions at $1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the order of the zero of the following functions at $1$:

$f(z)=e^{z-1}-1$ and $f(z)=z\sin(z-1)$

For $f(z)=e^{z-1}-1$ I found that it has a simple zero at $z=1$, i.e a zero of order $1$ at $z=1$.

The derivative of this function is just $e^{z-1}$, which never vanishes. Therefore the function cannot have zeroes of order higher than one.

Am I thinking about this correctly or is there more work needed using differentiation and Taylor Expansions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking correctly. And $1$ is also a simple zero of $z\sin(z-1)$, since its derivative at $1$ is not $0$.

Comment: Thanks.This may be a silly question but are they the only orders of $0$ at $1$ or is it possible for a function to have multiple orders of $0$ at a point?.

Comment: Sure. The order of $0$ as a zero of $z^n$ is $n$.

Comment: So for the functions above, the order of $0$ is just $1$ at the point $z=1$. Basically I'm just checking that they are fully solved.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.